# Local sidereal time interpretation

Tags: fundamental-astronomy, time

I am new to this domain and trying to *understanding the fundamentals of local sidereal time*.
Through an online available calculator https://www.iiap.res.in/personnel/reks/software/javascript/calclst.php ,I am noting down the `local sidereal time` for my `longitude` of interest. I have repeated the exercise for same time for five consecutive days. What I observe is that the `local sidereal time` is advancing by `0.06/07 hours per day` for the same time.Like `21.88 Hours` for current date and time , `21.94 Hours` for the same time next day ,`22.01 Hours` for next to next day and the pattern continues. *Kindly let me know how this increment is happening*?

Answer (score 2):

If you extrapolate, you'll find that those ~4 minutes per day add up to 24 hours per year.
The difference is due to the Earth revolving around the Sun at a rate of almost 1 degree per day.
For every 365$\frac{1}{4}$ solar days, there are 366$\frac{1}{4}$ sidereal days.

Civil time is based on mean
[solar time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_time),
in which the Sun crosses the
[celestial meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_%28astronomy%29)
every 24h 0m on average.
In [sidereal time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_time),
24h 0m is the time between successive meridian transits by any given star, equivalent to 23h 56m 4s of solar time.

Sidereal time also corresponds to the
[right ascension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_ascension)
of stars crossing the meridian at that time.
If a star in Orion has right ascension 5h 30m, then Orion is on the meridian at 05:30 sidereal time, which occurs 2 hours earlier in the solar day per month.